# SQLiteAssetHelper NullPointerException at getReadableDatabase()

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

Because [@CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) suggested (in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620086/3681880)) using the [Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) library, I decided not to use [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) method (a popular SO answer) to copy my pre-populated database from my assets folder to the app database folder.

Following the [Android SQLiteAssetHelper directions](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/blob/master/README.markdown), I set up my project like this:

Since I am using gradle, my database was in `src/main/assets/databases/test.db.zip`.

I used the `.zip` extension because the directions said

> Earlier versions of this library required the database asset to be
>   compressed within a ZIP archive. This is no longer a requirement, but
>   is still supported. Applications still targeting Gingerbread (API 10)
>   or lower should continue to provide a compressed archive to ensure
>   large database files are not corrupted during the packaging process.

and I want to support earlier versions of android.

My database class is similar to the following:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db.zip";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Again, I used the `.zip` extension for the `DATABASE_NAME` value because the directions said

> ...you must provide...a SQLite database inside the databases folder
>   whose file name matches the database name you provide in code
>   (including the file extension, if any)

However, when I do `SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();` I get a NullPointerException. What is the problem?

These SO questions and answers are not the same issue:

- [NullPointerException with Android SQLiteAssetHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14153768/nullpointerexception-with-android-sqliteassethelper)
- [SQLiteAssetHelper:Couldn't open database for writing (will try read-only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982367/sqliteassethelpercouldnt-open-database-for-writing-will-try-read-only)
- [SQLiteAssetHelper NullPointerException only on some devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20693417/sqliteassethelper-nullpointerexception-only-on-some-devices/29573749#29573749)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set up the question to make the answer somewhat obvious, but here it is:

Contrary to what the Android SQLiteAssetHelper directions make it sound like (at the time of this writing, anyway. hopefully they will clarity them in the future), the `DATABASE_NAME` value should not include the `.zip` extension. Change your code to

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test.db"; // no .zip extension
```

but keep `src/main/assets/databases/test.db.zip` as it is, and everything should work.